# vuejs - How to concatenate text to named route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How can I concatenate named route to router-link tag? My code:

```
<router-link
    :to="'//https://t.me/share/url?url='+{name: Profile, params: {id: user.user_id}}+'&text=Hi I am ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ':'">Click Here</router-link>
```

The problem is this part:

`{name: Profile, params: {id: user.user_id}}`

it returns `[Object object]`. How can I fix it to return correct value of this object which is `http://example.com/profile/1` as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `router-link` for external links, since it's click should not be processed with `vue-router`.

I'd suggest to create a computed property (or method) that will return a full url with all data included. Which also will remove certain logic from a template, as a good practice.

Template link will look as follow:

```
<a :href="telegramLink">Open Telegram</a>
```

And computed property to generate the link:

```
computed: {
  telegramLink () {
    const user = this.user

    // Get route information by provided parameters
    const route = this.$router.resolve({
      name: 'Profile',
      params: {
        id: user.user_id
      }
    })

    // Create full address url
    const url = `${window.location.origin}${route.href}`

    const text = `Hi I am ${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}:`

    return `https://t.me/share/url?url=${url}&text=${text}`
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a link using concatenating text and a variable by just adding a colon in front of to.

```
<router-link :to="'/districts/' + district.id " class="btn btn-danger cursor-pointer" title="Update District">
{{ district.id }}
</router-link>
```